# How can I turn off accessibility mode on my windows 10 laptop

Tags: iis, browser, accessibility, visual-studio-2019, large-fonts

When rendering apps on my Windows 10 laptop from Visual Studio 2019, I have started getting gigantic headers and footers compared to the content. This is multiple apps and multiple browsers.

Tried rendering on Edge, Chrome and Firefox. Tried different apps. Looked for settings in Windows for accessibility. Tried starting various apps through Local IIS as normal.

I was expecting the header and footer to be normal size, as always. This has never happened before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the Authentication mode in IIS for Windows Authentication to Enabled at the top IIS level (the IIS server). All of the auth modes were disabled at that level. I restarted IIS.

Since that did not make sense to me, I tried to recreate the problem by setting it back to Disable and restarting IIS, but that did not cause it to fail again.

I cannot remember if I actually restarted IIS when I was troubleshooting earlier. Maybe IIS just needed a restart.